# Get input from UITextField(HEX) data and send out via bluetooth LE

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, uint8t

i'm currently trying to get the data(HEX) from UITextfield, and i would want to store the data in UInt8 i'm currently doing this.

```
let incomingdata = UInt8(textfield.text!)
```

by doing this it returns nil. The purpose i'm doing this because after i gets the data from UITextField, i would send out the data in UInt8 format via bluetooth. Can someone suggest me how can i do that?Thank you

I update my question, in short i input 72AE in UITextField, i get the text in string format, but in the end i wan to convert it to UInt8 and it is in 0x72, 0xAE

In short, i'm converting HexString to UInt8

Comment: What does it print when you do `print(textfield.text!)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a hex value to an Int with this code.

```
let hex2int = String(format:"%2X", hex)
```

Quite easy.

Comment: Hi my input from text field is 72AE, in other word it is 0x72, 0xAE but i have difficulty to get it in Hex format, it is always treated as 7 2 A E and takes up 4 bytes where it is actually only 2 byte

Comment: If your trying to compress your data, then perhaps you should be taking a closer look at bitwise operators. Although a Uint8 is 8 bytes anyway surely. But you know in terms of bluetooth, your limitation is 20 characters per block, of course you can transmit more than one block. 72AE leaves you 16 characters. You could write a short routine that takes each character and creates a bitwise equivalent; which you would then OR together; to get your single 72AE byte if you will.

Comment: oh, i'm thinking of another way that not to compress the data. i'm doing this, convert the HexString to Int. But now the problem I'm facing is i can't convert Int to UInt8

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding your question, but if you would like to covert string into array of Int, this is how you might go about it.

```
let stringFromTextField = "anything"
// Convert stringFromTextField to NSString and then then convert it to NSData
// in encoding of your choosing
if let data = NSString(string: stringFromTextField).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) where data.length > 1 {
    // Create buffer
    var buffer: Int = 0
    let bufferSize = 1
    let adjustedDataLenght = data.length / bufferSize
    var yourInt = [Int]()
    // Loop over data and get bytes
    for i in 0..<adjustedDataLenght {
        data.getBytes(&buffer, range: NSRange(location: i, length: bufferSize))
        yourInt.append(buffer)
    }
    // Here are your ints
    print(yourInt)
}
```

Works in playground. Hope it helped.

Comment: i think there's some misunderstanding, i'm trying to convert HexString "72AE"  to Array[UInt8] [72, AE]